# adding a UIScrollView as a superview of 2 UITextview made no view can be scrolled

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

i have 2 textview in a viewcontroller. the 1st textview is not editable, but the 2nd is editable. i want to make both of them scroll in the same position and size when the keyboard is appear. I think i have to use UIScrollView as base of both of textview. And then i add the UIScrollView in xib (bot of textview are made in xib too). and this is the picture if this hierarchy :

[image]

in the viewDidLoad method, i add this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[scrollTextView addSubview:lineNumberTextView];
[scrollTextView addSubview:_codeTextView];

[lineNumberTextView bringSubviewToFront:scrollTextView];
[_codeTextView bringSubviewToFront:scrollTextView];
```

}

but after that  i can't scroll anything. What i have to do?
thx for the advices

**UPDATE**

this my code after do some advises like mac gave to me :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

scrollTextView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollTextView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;

_codeTextView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
_codeTextView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
_codeTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_codeTextView.tag = 0;
_codeTextView.delegate = self;

lineNumberTextView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
lineNumberTextView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
lineNumberTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
lineNumberTextView.tag = 1;
lineNumberTextView.delegate = self;
```

}

but just the _codeTextView scroll, the lineTextVew stil didn't scroll...somebody know why??

Answer (score 0):

Verify that user interaction enabled is checked in interface builder for the 2nd textview.

Comment: how if i want to made the 1st textview not editable and the 2nd textview editable? is there any advice?

Comment: i try to use Embed Object In from the xib, like example on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521308/how-to-add-uiscrollview-to-interface-builder, but the "Embed Object In" in my xib can not selected, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

you give some tag values for both the textfields, and in the delegate methods, do userinteraction enabled(false,true)whatever you required.

Comment: i have to do like that...give a tag to every textview, and set the userinteractionenabled:YES to both off them. but just the 2nd that scroll, the 1st is still didn't scroll