# Interface Builder place many items

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, interface-builder

I want to make screen with scroll view. How can I place items that will be shown after scroll in Interface Builder? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the elements you'd like to put in a scrollview then:

### In XCode4:

Click in the menu on `Editor -> Embed -> scrollview`.

### In XCode3:

Click in the menu on `Layout -> Embed Objects In -> scrollview`.

#### Have a look at How to add "[UIScrollView to Interface builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521308/how-to-add-uiscrollview-to-interface-builder)", there are several good solutions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

drag and drop UIcontrols on to the scrollView in the interface builder.

In inspector, change its frame where you want to place control in reference to the scrollview.