# Can't see UIScrollView content under 480px in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xcode4.2

I have all my buttons / labels / texts embedded in a uiscrollview. Everything works fine.  However, how do I see / edit beneath the 480px mark in IB? It cuts off the uiscrollview at the bottom.  I am using storyboarding in xcode 4.2 ios5.

Comment: I think your question may already be answered by this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135163/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. I have buttons BENEATH the scrollview 480px...I can not see them in interface builder. They are getting clipped off at the bottom.

Comment: There are a couple of workarounds suggested in the answers... one I like is having a separate view where you lay out your scroll view content, and then add that view to the scroll view in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you haven't yet found the answer and to save an answer. The solution is simple, but hard to find an answer on the web. Try this:

1. Select the Scroll View object
2. Select the Size Inspector (option-cmd-4)
3. Under View -> Y, enter a negative number (acts as scroll up)
4. Make sure View -> Height is large enough for the contents of your scroll view
5. Add, position and configure subview
6. (Optional) Set the View -> Y back to 0 for building

Before:

[image: Before]

After setting the Y value:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Can't imagine Xcode does not have a better way for users to edit the scroll view contents.