# Scrollview not moving at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I an making an extremely simple scrollview and doing it entirely in Interface Builder and cannot get it working.

According to `IB` the height of my `ScrollView` is 568.  I have set a user defined runtime attribute called `contentSize` and set it at 320x900.  Yet it simply will not scroll.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of my view:

[image]

If it was working, the word `label` should be bouncing all around, am I correct?  Nothing happens at all.  This is done entirely in `IB` I haven't touched code yet for this.

Comment: Is your label a subview of your scroll view?

Comment: how you have set the contentSize?

Comment: as a user defined runtime attribute in `IB`, i added a screenshot in my original post

Comment: @marcjacbson did you added scrolview to view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck the `AutoLayout` property in `IB`
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135163/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder).

Comment: +1 However, cocoa auto layout really isn't that bad. In fact, it should be used whenever possible. A better solution would be to set up the correct constraints in either IB or in code.