# Missing constraint x and height to UIScrollView in autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

Disclaimer: I saw a SO technique which includes adding an UIView (being called a contentView) to the UIScrollView and putting everything to this contentView. I don't want to use this technique as I would like to ***understand*** why I am having the current problem.

I have a UIScrollView on the default UIView of a UIViewController, its UIScrollView has 4 constraints: One on each side (trailing, top, leading, bottom) so that it glues to its parent the UIView.
**This works!**

[image: Working UIScrollView constraints]

But when I want to add an UIImageView to the UIScrollView and I want it to be glued to its parent sides (trailing, top, leading) + a specific height, now I have a problem.

[image: Non working UIImageView constraints]

It says:

```
Scroll View: Has ambiguous scrollable height
Scroll View: Needs constraints for: X position or width
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason xcode throws those error is because it cannot calculate `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` frame in the runtime.

when you add constraint for `UIScrollView` related to its superview, it tells xcode to draw scroll view as big as its superview. However, when you add constraint for `UIImageView` related to `UIScrollView` size, it tells xcode to draw image view as big as `UIScrollView` content size. please note that `UIScrollView` size and content size is two different thing.

if we think of it as a house, scroll view size is basically window size, it  is a size that you can use to see the inside of the house. And content size is the size of the house. which is why there is no relation between scroll view's size and content size.

you can fix your problem in two ways, first by set scroll view content size either programmatically or by using IB. Although, I'm not sure if setting it programmatically will silence the warning. You can set it in IB by following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135163/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder). second ways involving adding more constraint to your `UIImageView`. By adding bottom constraint and width constraint, xcode can calculate `UIScrollView` content size which will remove this warning.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the first option (the link), it couldn't silence the warning :/ The trick with adding an UIView (contentView) to the scrollView and doing everything in the UIView appears to be the easiest option (and futureproof if I add stuff into the view).

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue, I did the following thing:
 1. Inserted a scrollview. Gave it constraints to Superview from all directions
 2. Inside Scrollview, I added an another UIView.Then, I added similar constraints to Superview from all directions to the UIView as well. In addition to this, I gave it Vertically center alignment and Horizontally center Alignment. This removed the constraints errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Do the following in your storyborad

- Add a hidden view of height placed at 0,0 in your scrollview.
- Add constraints to the hidden view , top = 0 , left = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0.
- Add the constraint on this hidden view to make it center aling horizontally to the scroll view.

This should take care of the scrollview complaining about the x position.